# New parallel activity with data from the MainActivity

Tags: android, multithreading, maps

I am newbie in Android development.
I have an idea to create an application, which basically has 2 activities: Main and Map.
In Main activity the data collection and processing are going to be done. So it has all the fields and methods to get data, store it and update. It also has a small UI to display this data.
In Map activity I want to have a real-time reflection of the data from MainActivity on the map. So, when the data in MainActivity changes, it should also change in Map activity in real-time. 
The data itself includes location of certain devices in the building and their states.
I couldn't quite understand, if it is possible on Android to start a new Activity in parallel with MainActivity, which will be able to get changing data from MainActivity.
Can anybody advise my something for this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into Fragments

Comment: @LunarWatcher sounds reasonable. Can you post it as an answer, so I can check it as a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Fragments.

Google has several samples in the IDE you can use if you think the Android documentation is hard to understand.

Using master flow(sample) uses a fragment on tablets to display contents side-by-side(list and content in that example). But there are other samples as well using Fragments, and there is of course the [Android documentation on Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) as well.

See also these links:

[Building a Dynamic UI with Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html)

[Creating a Fragment](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html)